# faster more optimized way of file uploading

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

I am working on a image upload functionality in node.js in which I have an array of multiple file objects and in each array, the default storage file path is there if image and also a priority status. Like this

```
var imagesArr = [
    {path: "./img/img_3.jpg", priority: 3}, //exist
    {path: "./img/img_1.jpg", priority: 1}, //exist
    {path: "./img/img_5.jpg", priority: 5}, //exist
    {path: "./img/img_2.jpg", priority: 2}, //exist
    {path: "./img/img_4.jpg", priority: 4}, //exist
    {path: "./img/img_7.jpg", priority: 7}, //not exist
    {path: "./img/img_6.jpg", priority: 6}, //not exist
];
```

First, I need to sort out the array based on the priority. So I've done this to get new sorted array.

```
var sortedFileArr = imagesArr.sort(function(a, b) {return (a.priority > b.priority) ? 1 : ((b.priority > a.priority) ? -1 : 0);} );
```

Now, then I need to iterate the array to check if each file with given path is exists or not. If yes, then it will upload to a new target path. If no, then I re-check upto 3 times for that file it is exist. If not, then I need to send response that file is not found along with retry count. I've done this so far and it is working correctly. I am using async loop for iteration.

```
var resp = [];
async.each(sortedFileArr, function(fileArrItem, outerCallback) {
    var searchCount = 0, fileFoundStatus = false, retryCount = 0;
    while(searchCount <= 2) {
        if(fs.existsSync(fileArrItem.path)) {
            fileFoundStatus = true;
            retryCount = searchCount;
            break;
        } else {
            fileFoundStatus = false;
            retryCount = searchCount+1;
        }
        searchCount++;  
    }

    if(fileFoundStatus) {
        let imgName = fileArrItem.path.split("/")[2];
        fs.createReadStream(fileArrItem.path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./newImg/"+imgName));
        resp.push({name: fileArrItem.path, status: "Found", retryCount: retryCount})
        outerCallback();
    } else {
        resp.push({name: fileArrItem.path, status: "Not Found", retryCount: retryCount})
        outerCallback();
    }   
}, function(err){
    console.log(resp);
})
```

Now, my question is that can I do this in other simple way or more optimized way. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Checking the file more than once, with no delay, isn't likely to be helpful. Is it really possible that the file is created in between your checks?

Comment: This is for demo purpose and yeah,  there is some delay in checking the file.